# URL structure for inner pages?

Tags: directory-structure, seo

Say, I have a website which reviews cars. I have a page which contains a list of the best cars with the following url structure example.com/best-cars which contains links to the best cars pages. Should I link to example.com/best-cars/name-of-car or is it OK if the URL structure of the links is example.com/car/name-of-car ?

Comment: I can see how this is going to get all philosophical. IMHO the 2nd option will give you a more consistent url, while the 1st will (probably) give you better SEO. I'm no expert on this though.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. The last seems better SEO-wise, but if SEO is what you are really looking for, this may not be the best site for that question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to limit yourself with one path to the same page. With .htaccess redirects you can have multiple paths if you see that additional path is good for SEO. So basically you can support both suggested versions depending on the way visitor moving by your pages.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in duplicate content in Google?

Comment: I believe this is usual for web shops to have multiple paths to the same product page so Google is aware of this and behaves properly. It is the same as having multiple links to some page.